# Jquery Masked Input plugin allow dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events, maskedinput

I'm using JQuery Masked input plugin.

```
$("#percent").mask("99.99?9");
```

This allows numbers like `10.999, 10.99, 01.999, 01.99`

What I want to achieve is that I don't want user to type `01.99`. Instead if user types `1.99` I want `0` before `1` to be automatically added. This is how I started but don't know how to continue:

```
  //assume i typed in field 11.99
  $(document).on('keyup', '#percent', function(evt) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    alert(input); // 11.99_
    if(evt.which == '190' || evt.which == '110') {
       //if dot is clicked 
       alert(parseInt(input)); // 11
    }
});
```

Note that alert input prints `11.99_` with underscore at the end since third value is optional and I didnt input it.

Now this value is perfectly normal but if user entered `1.99`, would be unable since it would automatically move `9` towards `1` to fill it up with `2` digits, so it would return as `19.9` and this is invalid since there must be `2` decimals as defined above. So in my if statement I want to be able to detect if whatever was entered is less than `10`, if it's less than `10` in decimal points then add `0` at the beginning.

Ok I found a fix for `underscore _` :

```
    $("#percent").mask("99.99?9", {placeholder: ""})
```

but still does not fix other issue with entering `1.99` being `19.9`

Comment: a zero before a one does'nt make sense in a number, but if it's a number and you're converting it to a string, all you really need is `if (input<10) input = '0'+input;` to add a leading zero. In your case that would involve some splitting and parsing of numbers to get right. As a sidenote a value returned from an input is always a string.

Comment: yes but i want to change the field so that masked input does not dissapear. Masked input dissapears if something invalid is given.

Comment: You cannot do this with the mask plugin. I suggest you use regular expression as validator

Comment: I would like to see a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept keydown to do this, but you'll need some way to refresh plugin state.

The following code will do work:

```
$("#percent").bind({
    keydown: function(e) {
        // custom handler for dot
        var userInput = parseFloat($("#percent").val());
        if(e.which == '190' || e.which == '110') {
            // if entered number is integer and less than 10
            if(userInput % 1 === 0 && userInput < 10) {
                // prevent default mask input handlers from calling
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                // update value
                $("#percent").val('0'+userInput+'.');

                // simulate paste event to refresh mask input plugin state
                $("#percent").trigger('paste').trigger('input');
            }
        }       
    }
}).mask("99.99?9", {placeholder: ""});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NDGkA/)